# Отображения изображения в ListView - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Как отобразить изображения в ListView которые находятся в url?

```
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Logo", 120);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Название", 120);

        for (int i = 0; total_count > i; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem newitem = new ListViewItem(Convert.ToString(url));
            newitem.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(DeserializedObject.games[i].name)); listView1.Items.Add(newitem); }
```

Comment: WinForm или WPF?

Comment: WinForm проект у меня

Comment: С чем именно проблема: с получением изображения или с его добавлением в листвью?

Comment: С добавлением во listView1, изображение приходит мне с url